# Recompile Rails sass and css assets at runtime

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to build a GUI for customers to change colors, fonts, etc... but I'm not sure how to get Rails to recompile the sass/css assets without restarting the server.

Is this even possible, and if so, what's the trick?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Correct, if the actual css files are affected by outputting rails variables, you can't have both asset compilation and runtime variable substitutions at the same time.
You can always turn off asset compilation.

Comment: That is unfortunate. So what do folks when they want to let their clients change colors, style, etc? Surely the solution can't be to turn off asset compilation?